# How to know user close open dialog without saving?

Tags: c#, opendialog

```
SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();

sfd.ShowDialog();
sfd.Filter("Wave Files|*.wav");
ss.SetOutPutToWaveFile(sfd.FileName);
ss.Speak(richTextbox.Text);
ss.SetOutputToDefaultAudioDevice();
```

Comment: if not understand what I asking, please tell me. thanks

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e61ft40c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a return value from `sfd.ShowDialog()`:

```
if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    // File was selected
}
else
{
    // Cancelled
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK){

  //user  saved it
}
else {

   //write code to handle the case when an user does't save , and canceled it
}
```

Comment: do not use sfd.ShowDialog(); anymore. Erase  this line . And use it like I have shown.